# Do you know any place where I can find documentation for NConsoler?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

In one of my projects I want to implement NConsoler, command line parser library for .NET.

I have a problem to find a good documentation.

Are you aware of any place where I Can find a documentation for this API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find the documentation, but in the source code there are [some usage examples](http://code.google.com/p/nconsoler/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples) which are better than docs IMHO.

**Update:** [Here](http://nconsoler.csharpus.com/manual/) is the manual. Looks like it's simple and to the point.